# Top Empty Space Added in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, insets

I created an `ScrollView` Programatically using swift
I added a `UIView` in it
After adding these both to `view` it shows Empty Space on Top of the `ScrollView`
How can i remove that, i searched in google and i found several and i tried them

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

and

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0.0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0.0);
scrollContainer.contentInset = insets;
```

please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the navigation bar and bottom tab bar.
So your inset should be like this:

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

If you are using storyboard and auto layout, then you need to following the setting below:

[image]